# How to use "COUNT" with "GROUP BY" & "WHERE"

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

```
SELECT `loanac`.`id`, `loanac`.`area`
FROM loanac, loantrans
WHERE `loanac`.`lacc`=`loantrans`.`account`
GROUP BY `loanac`.`lacc`
HAVING SUM(IFNULL(`loantrans`.`out`,0)) > SUM(IFNULL(`loantrans`.`in`,0))
```

QUERY RESULT:

```
----------------------------------------
id      area
----------------------------------------
5       A
165     C
166     C
167     C
232     D
91      B
```

This Query gives me all id & area for lacc's who have out>in, this query is is OK & working, I just need to get output GROUP BY area and COUNT id from this query. Can anyone help?

What I want is

```
----------------------------------------
COUNT(id)      GROUP BY(area)
----------------------------------------
1               A
5               B
9               C
1               D
```

NOTE: The conditions aren't change
Target: Want to find/count number of (loanac.id) grouping by (loanac.area) with same conditions

Comment: `FROM loanac INNER JOIN loantrans ON loanac.lacc=loantrans.account`  don't use old fashioned join syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you're asking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), area FROM
  (SELECT id, area FROM loanac
     JOIN loantrans ON loanac.lacc = loantrans.account
     GROUP BY loanac.lacc
     HAVING SUM(IFNULL(loantrans.out, 0)) > SUM(IFNULL(loantrans.in,0))) t
  GROUP BY area;
```

Above, I have a group by `loanac.area` because that's what the original example looks like. If you want to group by `loanac.lacc`, just change the `GROUP BY` above to, `GROUP BY loanac.lacc`.

**EDIT:** Loading in the test database linked in the comment and running the query yields:

```
+-----------+------+
| COUNT(id) | area |
+-----------+------+
|        86 | A    |
|        81 | B    |
|        64 | C    |
|        66 | D    |
|        20 | E    |
|         3 | F    |
+-----------+------+
```

Comment: Bro, tried as you directed BUT, this query is not maintaining this condition "HAVING SUM(loantrans.out) > SUM(loantrans.in)".
Any suggestion?

Comment: @Machine I updated my answer and insert the `IFNULL`. I wasn't sure if it would work without it. See if that fixes it.

Comment: Bro, now it's not grouping by id, i need to group by id, then area. Here is my db uploaded for you, will u please take a look.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/or8hf4rza2ut736/bankdb.sql_4.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Machine what do you mean "group by id" in this case? The `id` doesn't appear in your example since you are just showing a count of multiple, different id's per area. Your example showed grouped and ordered by area. Perhaps you could show a more illustrative example.

Comment: Bro, please check the screenshot uploaded here https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcsuxn8gxd8gp37/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: @Machine your screen shot shows your tables plus the query you already have that you aren't happy with. You're saying to GROUP BY the `id`. But if you want a count of `id` as you show in your question under "What I want" then you cannot have both. If you group by `id`, you can't also provide a count of `id`. So it is unclear what you want your results to look like. Perhaps you could update the "What I want" table in your problem statement. It needs to show how you want to group by `id` and by `area`. Right now, it just groups by `area` and counts `id`.

Comment: Bro, screenshot updated https://www.dropbox.com/s/zcsuxn8gxd8gp37/Capture.PNG?dl=0 will you please take a look. Actually all I want is to find which area have how many active accounts.

Comment: @Machine I'm sorry, I don't see how the results of my answer differ from what's underlined as the requirement in that screenshot or your example desired result. See my updated answer for results from the data you linked. Let me know exactly what's not correct about it.

Comment: Bro, "count(loanac.id)" is counting id's multiple times, each id's can't be counted more than once, only then I'll get desired result. Any idea? :(

Comment: Bro, just little, little bit correction needed, the query is not maintaining this condition "HAVING SUM(IFNULL(loantrans.out,0)) > SUM(IFNULL(loantrans.in,0))". WIth or without this condition, result is same

Comment: @Machine I reconsidered the approach and leveraged your working `SELECT` in my latest update.

Comment: You did it! It worked! Thank you very much. May god fulfill your wishes :)

Comment: Bro can u help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026668/how-to-use-opposite-of-between-in-a-mysql-query/26040410#26040410 Messed up with "NOT BETWEEN" here are the screenshots https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lgmop3zxqaf9mjy/AAAWVWjZXd8da9KDDOqz2ANla?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

i think you want something like this.  Add `area` to your GROUP BY line, and use COUNT(id) to get the count of transactions.

```
SELECT count(`loanac`.`id`),
       SUM(IFNULL(`loantrans`.`out`,0)) AS transout,
       SUM(IFNULL(`loantrans`.`in`,0)) AS transin,
       `loanac`.`area`,
       `loanac`.`lacc`
FROM loanac, loantrans
WHERE `loanac`.`lacc`=`loantrans`.`account`
GROUP BY `loanac`.`lacc`,`loanac`.`area`
HAVING transout > transin
```

EDIT: To give output you are looking for

```
SELECT count(loanac.id), `loanac`.`area`
FROM loanac, loantrans
WHERE `loanac`.`lacc`=`loantrans`.`account`
GROUP BY `loanac`.`lacc`,`loanac`.`area`
HAVING SUM(IFNULL(`loantrans`.`out`,0)) > SUM(IFNULL(`loantrans`.`in`,0))
```

Comment: I think I couldn't make it clear enough to understand, information is been updated. Will you please take a look again and suggest anything?

Comment: Bro, tried as you directed, but area is not grouping. Here is the db uploaded for you. Will you please take a look. https://www.dropbox.com/s/gz8f4ejvbgxehbp/bankdb.sql_2.zip?dl=0