# How to use opposite of BETWEEN in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a working query which used "BETWEEN" to find results within a date range, what i need is just opposite result or not between the given date range. Here is the query below.

```
SELECT loanac.id, loanac.name, loanac.lacc, loanac.phone, 
SUM(loantrans.in) as totalin, SUM(loantrans.out) as totalout 

FROM loanac, loantrans 
WHERE (loanac.lacc=loantrans.account) 
AND (`loantrans`.`date` BETWEEN CAST('$range' AS DATE) AND CAST('$date' AS DATE))

GROUP BY loanac.lacc
HAVING SUM(IFNULL(`loantrans`.`out`,0)) > SUM(IFNULL(`loantrans`.`in`,0))
```

Can anyone help me finding opposite result or result of not between the date range having the same conditions?

Details Screenshots here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lgmop3zxqaf9mjy/AAAWVWjZXd8da9KDDOqz2ANla?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that, somehow, the expressions that define the date interval are returning a time section (those `strtotime()` look like the culprits). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347649/sql-between-not-inclusive/16347721#16347721) deals with two options (option 2 is the good one) when the date includes a time part.

In your specific case, I think this would be the best approach to solve the issue:

```
SELECT loanac.id, loanac.name, loanac.lacc, loanac.phone
     , SUM(loantrans.in) as totalin, SUM(loantrans.out) as totalout 
FROM loanac
     INNER JOIN loantrans on loanac.lacc = loantrans.account
-- Instead of an implicit join in the WHERE clause, use an explicit INNER JOIN
WHERE date(loantrans.date) < date('$range')  
  AND date(loantrans.date) > date('$date')
GROUP BY loanac.lacc
HAVING SUM(IFNULL(`loantrans`.`out`,0)) > SUM(IFNULL(`loantrans`.`in`,0))
```

Notice that the `date()` function "removes" the time section of the value.

---

One more thing: Your code may be vulnerable to **SQL Injection attacks**. Please [take a look here](http://bobby-tables.com) for a (humorous) example on what it is, and tips on how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your $date and $range are simply "now" and "6 days ago", there is **NO** reason to be generating the dates in PHP. Why not simply

```
WHERE datefield BETWEEN (curdate() - INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND curdate()
a.k.a.
WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2014-09-19' AND '2014-09-25'
a.k.a
WHERE (datefield >= '2014-09-19') AND (datefield <= '2014-09-25')
```

for which the opposite (`NOT`) would be

```
WHERE (datefield > curdate()) OR (datefield < (curdate() - INTERVAL 6 DAY))
a.k.a
WHERE (datefield > '2014-09-25') OR (datefield < '2014-09-19')
```

Comment: Sorry, not working, here is the screenshots in details https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lgmop3zxqaf9mjy/AAAWVWjZXd8da9KDDOqz2ANla?dl=0

Comment: that picture doesn't help at all. you're showing records for lacc 975,976, and loantrans for 1010. the two snippets aren't related at all.